# How to split observations in Stata

Tags: split, stata

I've been trying to make the following transformation in my Stata dataset:
[image]
`Number`, `Cluster` and `Rating` are my three variables. All values are strings.

Do you have any Stata-specific suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand. Is this a string variable? You need to provide a [mcve] ideally using `dataex`.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Sorry, is this version clearer?

Comment: It is better but be advised that proper examples that can readily be used in Stata are strongly preferred compared to just linking or uploading pictures. Can you also include the code that you have tried and  apparently did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the lack of a good data example or attempted code, suggestions can be made:

```
clear
input str7 Number str3 Cluster str6 Rating
"017;092" "Z12" "High"  
"400;401" "Z14" "Medium"
"523"     "Z98" "Low"   
end

replace Number = subinstr(Number, ";", " ", .)
gen count = wordcount(Number)
gen long id = _n
expand count
bysort id : replace Number = word(Number, _n)

list, sepby(id)

     +----------------------------------------+
     | Number   Cluster   Rating   count   id |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |    017       Z12     High       2    1 |
  2. |    092       Z12     High       2    1 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  3. |    400       Z14   Medium       2    2 |
  4. |    401       Z14   Medium       2    2 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  5. |    523       Z98      Low       1    3 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```

The code here hinges on an assumption that once semi-colons are removed from `Number` the remaining elements all count as words in Stata's sense. If that's not the case, you should spell out what is problematic and alternative code can be suggested.

EDIT: More general code:

```
clear
input str7 Number str3 Cluster str6 Rating
"017;092" "Z12" "High"  
"400;401" "Z14" "Medium"
"523"     "Z98" "Low"   
end

split Number, parse(;)
local nvars : word count `r(varlist)' 
gen long id = _n
expand `nvars' 

forval j=1/`nvars' { 
    bysort id: replace Number = Number`j' if _n == `j' 
}

drop if missing(Number) 

list, sepby(id)
```

Comment: I am all for suggestions but this looks like homework and someone simply asking for a solution. Have seen this during review several times.

Comment: If this is homework then it's not trivial in my view. Even if the answer expected starts with `split` (which I do know about!) then there is  still some further stuff yet to come.

Comment: I like your solution. But is the last step always generalizable?

Comment: The last paragraph addresses this. A more general solution could use `split`.